# Sci Fi book where space ship has artificial intelligence

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence

The Captain had already lost two space ships and was given a third. The third ship's name was Gage.  It considered itself alive.

The Captain was injured while rescuing the crew on the second ship.

They travel faster than light but never actually move (that's the way it is described).

The new ship almost replaces the Captain until talked out of it by the engineer.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site! :) Maybe you could add some info if [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) triggers new memories about the book? The more info, the more chances to identify it!

Comment: Faster than light? You mean, these ships are SPACE ships? Is that right? That might be worth mentioning right at the beginning.

Comment: @user14111 - An FTL sea-going vessel would be pretty useless. Unless you wanted to blow up instantly and take out half the Atlantic, obviously.

Comment: @Valorum My point was that you don't talk about "ships" for three paragraphs, and then in paragraph four reveal that the "ships" are actually **space** ships.

Comment: Well, arguably there was Flint’s series about semi-sentient wooden sailing ships which allowed space travel.

Comment: Was this a single book or a series? Were there any notable subplots?

Answer (score 2):

The book is 'The Artifact' by W. Michael Gear. 'Gage' was the name of the AI in the ship that was lost.  Good book. I highly recommend it.

[Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075PVRW95)